# Create deep nested array in prisma mongodb nextjs

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma, next.js13

i try to make array of colors for every size in product

every product have multiple sizes and every size have multiple colors witch has a stock

when i use createMany it doesn't work

i try create then createMany and it doesn't work either

Schema :

```
model Category {
  id        String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name      String
  gender    String
  image     String?
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime  @updatedAt
  user      User?     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    String?   @db.ObjectId
  products  Product[]
}

model Size {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  size      String?
  colors    Colors[]
  Product   Product? @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId String?  @db.ObjectId
}

model Colors {
  id    String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  color String?
  stock Int?
  size   Size?   @relation(fields: [sizeId], references: [id])
  sizeId String? @db.ObjectId
}

model Images {
  id  String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  url String
  Product   Product? @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId String?  @db.ObjectId
}

model Product {
  id            String          @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String
  description   String?
  rating        Int?
  total_sell    Int?
  sold_out      Int?
  createdAt     DateTime        @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime        @updatedAt
  images        Images[]
  sizes         Size[]
  category      Category?       @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId    String?         @db.ObjectId
  user          User?           @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        String?         @db.ObjectId
  packages      Package[]       @relation(fields: [packageId], references: [id])
  packageId     String[]        @db.ObjectId
  cartItem      CartItem[]
  ProductRating ProductRating[]
}
```

the POST Reqeust

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
    try {
        const body = await request.json();
        const newProduct = await prisma.product.create({
            data: {
                name: body.name,
                description: body.description,
                images: {
                    createMany: {
                        data: [
                            { url: body.images.url }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                category: {
                    create: {
                        name: body.category.name,
                        gender: body.category.gender
                    }
                },
                sizes: {
                    create: [
                        {
                            size: body.sizes.size,
                            colors: {
                                createMany: {
                                    data: [
                                        {
                                            color: body.sizes.colors.color,
                                            stock: body.sizes.colors.stock,
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            include: {
                category: true,
                images: true,
                sizes: {
                    include: {
                        colors: true
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        if (!newProduct) throw NextResponse.json({
            message: "Failed creating new product",
            status: 404,
        });

        return NextResponse.json(newProduct, { status: 200, });
    } catch (error) {
        throw NextResponse.json({
            message: "Product Created Failed",
            error,
            status: 500,
        });
    }
}
```

i try to createMany inside create but it didn't work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What _did_ happen?

Comment: mean it didnt create the product